# Is there a concise word for nth largest that is a generalisation of "maximum"?

Tags: notation

$$
\max_{x \in {X}} f(x)
$$

Means I want the maximum value of $f$ under all possible values of $x \in X$

---

Is there a way to say the above but for the second maximum (ie once you remove the $x$ that gives the maximum, what is the new maximum)? What about nth maximum?

PS: and let's say $X$ is a discrete set.

Comment: You may be referring to $\mathrm{arg\,max}$.

Comment: @soupless hmm I don't think so. That would be "the value of $x$ that maximizes $f(x)$".

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.

Comment: The second-place maximum value seems like it wouldn't come up enough to warrant a notation, but I can't prove a negative.